# change url in hikashop module

Tags: joomla, megamenu

I use joomla, hikashop and  JUX Mega Menu for HikaShop .

juxmegamenu works properly but I want to change url of these module as below:

ex:
http://example.com/component/hikashop/product/listing/12-laptop

to 
http://example.com/shop/product/listing/12-laptop

problem is:
JUX Mega Menu for HikaShop has no option for assign a menu(for example shopmenu with shop alias) to menu item generated.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're trying to change the alias of your shop. It's not about menu and is controlled by Hikashop. Go to Hikashop's global configuration and change the URL of your store. So, it'll be applied to the whole store.

Comment: this is true. but I didn't know how to do it.